# yii2 log target mask

Tags: php, logging, yii2

I am using the Yii2 framework and need to find a way to protect sensitive data that is going to the log files.

Consider the following log dump

```
$_POST = [
'_csrf' => 'VzVDNC03aXk9BAhOYEMPPzkDG2BvQwELDwZuV2VzUDUjTSJuRl4FCQ=='
'CreditCardForm' => [
    'card_number' => '4111111111111111'
    'exp_month' => '02'
    'exp_year' => '16'
    'cardholder_name' => 'Jane Doe'
    'agreement' => '1'
]
```

]

I would like to modify the behavior of \yii\log\Target.getContextMessage() in a portable way without touching the framework files so that the first 12 digits of the credit card number are masked.

My current thought is to alter $_POST global after making a copy of the values into the model that does the processing.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web/index.php I added the following

```
global $SAFE_POST;
if(is_array($_POST)) {
  $SAFE_POST = $_POST;
  array_walk_recursive($SAFE_POST,function(&$value,$key) {
    if($key == 'card_number' && is_string($value)) {
       if(strlen($value) <= 4)
         $value = str_repeat('X',strlen($value));
       else
         $value = str_repeat('X',strlen($value)-4).substr($value,-4);
    }
  });
}
```

Then I configured my LogTarget to use the new global.

```
log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'info'],
                    'logVars' => ['_GET', 'SAFE_POST', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_SESSION', '_SERVER']    
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can opt to change the configuration of your log routes to not include POST by using your config file and change the content of `logVars`. If you don't need the superglobals at all you can just set it to `[]`

Eg:

```
'components' => [
   'log' => [
      'targets' => [
     ...
     'logVars' = ['_GET', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_SESSION', '_SERVER'],
     ...
    ]
 ]
```

A different alternative would be to override the `Target`-class you use and update the `getContextMessage()` function to remove/blur the creditcard numbers before you return the data.

Comment: I'm thinking about replacing _POST from logVars with a new _MASKED_POST global that I will create early in the startup sequence, possibly in web/index.php